# Pushing multiple arrays to slice into one || PHP

Tags: php

So I have something like:

```
$array = array("red", "yellow", "hello", "world");
$array2 = array("1", "2", "3", "4");

$myArray = array();
array_push($myArray, $array, $array2 );
$myArray = array_slice($myArray, 0, 2);
```

and I want $myArray to be ["red", "yellow"], and if $array was empty $myArray would be ["1", "2"]

Does that make any sense? Right now array_slice is counting the arrays being pushed into $myArray, not the content inside them. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: So, you want the first two elements of `$array` and if it is empty get the first two elements of `$array2`?

Comment: Exactly, and if $array only has one element it will take the first of $array and the first of $array2

Comment: `array_push($myArray, $array, $array2);` doesn't do what you think it does.  This adds 2 elements to `$myArray`, both of which are arrays.  I think you want `array_merge`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where you use `array_push` you probably want to use [`array_merge`](http://php.net/array_merge):

```
$array = array("red", "yellow", "hello", "world");
$array2 = array("1", "2", "3", "4");

$myArray = array_merge($array, $array2);
$myArray = array_slice($myArray, 0, 2);
```

Explanation:

`array_push` pushes the elements to the end of the existing array, so

```
$array = array('a');
array_push($array, 'b');
// results in $array = array('a', 'b');
```

Thus in your code, just after the `array_push`-call

```
$myArray = array(array('red', 'yellow', ...), array('1', '2', ...))
```

`array_merge` merges two or more arrays

```
$myArray = array_merge($array, $array2);
// results in $myArray = array('red', 'yellow', ..., '1', '2', ...)
```

Comment: Great explanation, just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/array_merge) instead of `array_push()`

```
$array = array("red", "yellow", "hello", "world");
$array2 = array("1", "2", "3", "4");

$myArray = array_merge($array, $array2 );
$myArray = array_slice($myArray, 0, 2);
```

`array_push()` is adding each array as an element of `$myArray` instead of combining them with it.